# Spotify iframe embed white theme loads with black theme player and white theme playlist

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe, spotify

Embedding a Spotify playlist as an iframe on my hosted Wordpress website with the parameter `&theme=white` and roughly half the time when the page loads the playlist portion of the player is the white theme but the top of the player (with the name of the playing track and the playlist name, etc.) is the black theme.  Doesn't matter the dimensions of the `iframe` or the page it's on, it happens all over the website.

I can see that when it loads incorrectly the body tag of the iframe has class `ab-control playlist view-list white mode-large` and when it loads correctly (the whole player is the white theme) the class of the body tag is `theme-white`.

How can this inconsistency be remedied so that the whole player loads the white theme every time?

[Small-ish player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVd1Q.png)

[Large player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YLhL.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is part of an A/B test in which we (Spotify) are trying out 2 different versions of the component. Hopefully we will be done soon and all the buttons will look consistent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For the record, +1 for the all white.